# Undefined subroutine &main::unlock

Tags: multithreading, perl

I wrote this:

```
use threads;

    lock($lock);
        cond_wait($full,$lock) while($threads == $max_thread);
        $threads++;
    unlock($lock);
```

After running this code, I am given the error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::unlock called at ./pages.pl line 222, <FH> line 1.`
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `$threads >= $max_thread` would be safer (handle bugs more robustly)

Comment: thx! i thought the same... but in the end i just wrote == anyway... but now i reconsidered to write >= because your advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[perlthrtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html)

> Note that there is no unlock() function - the only way to unlock a
>   variable is to allow it to go out of scope.

So,

```
{
    lock($lock);
    cond_wait($full,$lock) while($threads == $max_thread);
    $threads++;
}
```